# how to properly wrap method.invoke() (reflect) in a reactive java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to make a service in reactive java,
another service will send me requests.
I catch these requests and want to run methods according to the incoming URI

Here I receive a request from another service and run the desired method:

```
public Mono<Response> requestResponse(Request message, ByteBuf metadata) {
        return controller.startMethod(message)
                .onErrorResume(error -> Mono.just(buildResponse(error.getMessage(), message, Status.STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(buildResponse("NULL", message, Status.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST)))
                .doOnNext(logResponse());
    }
```

This is the launch itself, the method is located by the annotation and the http method

```
public Mono<Response> startMethod(Request message) {
        for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (isNecessaryMethod(method, message)) {
                try {
                    return (Mono<Response>) method.invoke(context.getBean(clazz), initParameters(method, message));
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    return Mono.error(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return Mono.error(new PathNotFound());
    }
```

Subsequently, the method should run, this is an example:

```
@Request(url = "/save-token", method = POST)
    public Mono<Response> saveToken(String token) {

        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

I would like to know how to properly process method.invoke(...) so that everything works reactively and correctly

Comment: If this is a real app, you might want to be cautious about letting visitors to your web page reflectively choose what method to invoke...

Comment: What could be the danger?

Comment: Visitors to your website calling `System.exit`, or calling some method that they shouldn't have permissions to like `dumpAllDebuggingInformation`, or calling `getPassword()`, or any of a hundred things.  Doing reflection based on the data passed by users to your website is pretty much #1 on the list of security no-nos in Java.

Comment: In my case, only certain methods marked with an annotation can be called. The method is selected according to the sent url in the requestv (/send-token)
In the future, I will add roles, but for now I wanted to deal with java reactive

Comment: remote invokation is dangerous and should be avoided at all costs, if someone annotates something wrong or you have a bug, this can have very dire consequences